# OSX Mavericks - Upgraded PHP not loading

Tags: macos, php, osx-mavericks

I was wondering if someone could help me.

Im running mavericks OSX ... When i type php -v i get the following:

```
PHP 5.4.24
```

I needed to upgrade the PHP version, so i followed an online guide and updated via the command

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.5
```

The installation seems to be successful, and installs the new php to

```
/usr/local/php5/bin/php
```

But when i run php -v from the command line, i still get the same php version as in the beginning.

If i run /usr/local/php5/bin/php -v i get the correct version im looking for, which is

```
PHP 5.5.13
```

Also, when i run which php i get

```
/usr/bin/php
```

How do i change it so that when i type php -v it shows the updated version?

One more thing .. Im using the zsh shell.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Unix shells look for an environment variable called `PATH` to tell them a prioritized list of directory paths in which to look for commands (executable files). Your `PATH` variable needs to have `/usr/local/php5/bin` before `/usr/bin` if you want it to find your new custom local version of PHP instead of the default system version.

To do this on the fly, enter this command:

```
PATH="/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH"
```

To make this change stick for your account, add that command to the appropriate startup script for `zsh`, such as `.zshenv`, `.zshrc`, or `.zshprofile`.

To make this change stick for all shells for all accounts on your system, add `/usr/local/php5/bin` to the top of `/etc/paths`.